# Using Multi select grid sencha ext js 4.1

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4.1, multi-select, sencha-architect

I am new to Sencha. In one of my projects I have to use a Multiselect Grid Panel and update the store to and from the Grid. I have no clue as to how to achieve this. 
I will highly appreciate if someone can send me their sample code or even links that display the usage of Multiselect grids. I found a few but unfortunately those links dont use Ext JS 4.1.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, have a look at the API docs:

- http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.selection.RowModel-cfg-mode
- http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example

Then look at the infinite grid example:

- http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/grid/infinite-scroll.html

Oddly enough, this example uses an undocumented "multiSelect" config on the grid... but it could have been defined on the selection model per the API docs.